# chrome createAnswer does not gather srvflx candidates

Tags: webrtc

I've configured STUN server.

chrome's createAnswer does not gather srvflx candidates.
It gathers only host candidates.

But firefox's createAnswer does.
Also chrome's createOffer does.

Some configuration is needed?

my code snippet is here.

```
var iceConfig = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'],
      url:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
    }
  ]
};

pc = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfig);

pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
  var candidate = event.candidate;
  // only host candidates on chrome
};

var rjsep = new RTCSessionDescription(jsep);
pc.setRemoteDescription(rjsep).then(function() {
  pc.createAnswer().then(function(ansJsep) {
    pc.setLocalDescription(ansJsep).then(function() {
      Socket.emit('answer', ansJsep);
    }, function(err) {
      Message.info(err);
    });
  }, function(err) {
    // createAnswer error
    Message.info(err);
  });
}, function(err) {
  // setRemoteDescription error
  Message.info(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm, It seems that it depends on remote SDP.
I used some SFU, and this issue happens.

It works fine when browsers connect directly.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome stops gathering candidates once the iceConnectionState becomes connected (or completed) which might lead to the behaviour you are describing.